# Is there any workaround to make Firebird v2.5 under Arch Linux attach existing databases and open them?

Tags: linux, firebird

I have tried almost everything to get Firebird v2.5 under Arch Linux connect to an existing .fdb database without getting the error message:

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database failed

SQL Message : -902
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements

Engine Code    : 335544831
Engine Message :
Use of database at location /home/tomay/Firebird/GEA.fdb is not allowed by server configuration
```

- I have added user '**tomay**' to group '**firebird**'
- I have added user '**firebird**' to group '**tomay**'

```sh
[tomay@tomay-pc ~]$ id tomay
uid=1000(tomay) gid=1001(tomay) groups=1001(tomay),998(wheel),991(lp),3(sys),90(network),98(power),1000(autologin),184(firebird)
[tomay@tomay-pc ~]$ id firebird
uid=184(firebird) gid=184(firebird) groups=184(firebird),1001(tomay)
```

- I have changed '**/home/tomay/Firebird/**' directory permissions to '**firebird**' user and '**firebird**' group.
- I have tried '**isql-fb**', '**FlameRobin**' and '**DBeaver**'.
- I have edited '**/etc/firebird/firebird.conf**' as follows:

```
#######################################
#
# Firebird configuration file
#
# Comments
# --------
# The # character is used for comments and can be placed anywhere on a
# line.  Anything following the # character on a line is considered a
# comment.
#
# Examples:
#
#    # This is a comment
#    DefaultDbCachePages = 2048   # This is an end-of-line comment
#
# Entries
# -------
# The default value for each entry is listed to the right of the "=".
# To activate an entry, remove the leading "#"s and supply the desired
# value.
#
# Please note, a number of the values are specified in **Bytes** (Not KB).
# Accordingly, we have provided some simple conversion tables at the bottom
# of this file.
#
# There are three types of configuration values: integer, boolean and string.
#
# Integer
# --------
# Integers is what they sound like, an integral value. Examples:
#   1
#   42
#   4711
#
# Boolean
# -------
# Boolean is expressed as integer values with 0 (zero) being "false" and
# non-zero is taken to mean "true". For consistency we recommend you
# only use 0/1.
#
# String
# ------
# Strings are also what they sound like, strings. Examples:
#   RootDirectory  = /opt/firebird
#   RemotePipeName = pipe47
#
#
# Portions of this file have been reproduced/made available with the
# permission of Ann Harrison @ IBPhoenix.
#
#######################################

# ==================================
# Settings for all platforms/engines
# ==================================
#
# ----------------------------
# Specify the root directory under which Firebird is installed.
# Can be used to override the OS-specifically determined one.
#
# Type: string
#
#RootDirectory =


# ----------------------------
# Database Paths/Directories
#
# DatabaseAccess may be None, Full or Restrict. If you choose Restrict,
# provide ';'-separated trees list, where database files are stored.
# Relative paths are treated relative to RootDirectory entry
# (see above). Default value 'Full' gives full access to all files
# on your site. To specify access to specific trees, enum all required
# paths (for Win32 this may be something like 'C:\DataBase;D:\Mirror',
# for unix - '/db;/mnt/mirrordb'). If you choose 'None', then only
# databases listed in aliases.conf can be attached.
#
# Note: simple quotation marks shown above should *NOT* be used when
# specifying values and directory path names. Examples:
#
# DatabaseAccess = None
# DatabaseAccess = Restrict C:\DataBase
# DatabaseAccess = Restrict C:\DataBase;D:\Mirror
# DatabaseAccess = Restrict /db
# DatabaseAccess = Restrict /db;/mnt/mirrordb
# DatabaseAccess = Full
#
# UNCONTROLLED DATABASE ACCESS MAY COMPROMISE YOUR SYSTEM!
# IT IS STRONGLY RECOMMENDED THAT THIS SETTING BE USED TO LIMIT
# DATABASE LOCATIONS!
#
# Type: string (special format)
#
DatabaseAccess = None


# ----------------------------
# External File Paths/Directories
#
# ExternalFileAccess may be None, Full or Restrict. If you choose
# Restrict, provide ';'-separated trees list, where external files
# are stored. Relative paths are treated relative to RootDirectory entry
# (see above). Default value 'None' disables any use of external files
# on your site. To specify access to specific trees, enum all required
# paths (for Win32 this may be something like 'C:\ExternalTables',
# for unix - '/db/extern;/mnt/extern').
#
# NOTE: THE EXTERNAL TABLE ENGINE FEATURE COULD BE USED TO COMPROMISE
# THE SERVER/HOST AS WELL AS DATABASE SECURITY!!
#
# IT IS STRONGLY RECOMMENDED THAT THIS SETTING BE USED TO LIMIT
# EXTERNAL TABLE LOCATIONS!
#
# Type: string (special format)
#
#ExternalFileAccess = None


# ----------------------------
# External Function (UDF) Paths/Directories
#
# UdfAccess may be None, Full or Restrict. If you choose
# Restrict, provide ';'-separated trees list, where UDF libraries
# are stored. Relative paths are treated relative to RootDirectory entry
# (see above).
#
# Default value 'Restrict UDF' provides the same restrictions
# as in FB 1.0. To specify access to specific trees, enum all required
# paths (for Win32 this may be something like 'C:\ExternalFunctions',
# for unix - '/db/extern;/mnt/extern').
#
#  #  For this build Restrict UDF means Restrict /usr/lib/firebird/UDF
#
# NOTE: THE EXTERNAL FUNCTION ENGINE FEATURE COULD BE USED TO COMPROMISE
# THE SERVER/HOST AS WELL AS DATABASE SECURITY!!
#
# IT IS STRONGLY RECOMMENDED THAT THIS SETTING BE USED TO LIMIT
# EXTERNAL FUNCTION LOCATIONS!
#
# Type: string (special format)
#
#UdfAccess = Restrict UDF
#UdfAccess = None


# ----------------------------
# Temporary directories
#
# Provide ';'-separated trees list, where temporary files are stored.
# Relative paths are treated relative to RootDirectory entry
# (see above). Default value is determined using FIREBIRD_TMP,
# TEMP or TMP environment options. Once the first specified
# directory has no available space, the engine will switch to the
# next one, and so on.
#
# E.g.:
# TempDirectories = c:\temp
# or
# TempDirectories = c:\temp;d:\temp
#
# Type: string (special format)
#
#TempDirectories =


# ----------------------------
# Legacy hash makes possible use of old security.fdb
# after running misc/upgrade/security_database.sql.
# If you want to disable logons with old passwords
# after users' migration, set it to 0 (false).
# Makes no difference when used with original
# security2.fdb - it can't contain DES hash.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#LegacyHash = 1

# ----------------------------
# Which authentication method(s) should be used.
# "native" means use of only traditional interbase/firebird
# authentication with security database.
# "trusted" (Windows Only) makes use of window trusted authentication,
# and in some aspects this is the most secure way to authenticate.
# "mixed" means both methods may be used.
#
# Type: string
#
#Authentication = native


# ----------------------------
# Trace configuration file for system audit
#
# Empty value means that system audit is turned off.
#
# Type: string
#
#AuditTraceConfigFile =

# ----------------------------
# Maximum summary size of each user trace session's log files in MB.
# When log files size reach this limit, trace session automatically 
# suspends until interactive user service read and delete some log files.
#
# Type: integer
#
#MaxUserTraceLogSize = 10


# ----------------------------
# Number of cached database pages
#
# This sets the number of pages from any one database that can be held
# in cache at once. If you increase this value, the engine will
# allocate more pages to the cache for every database. By default 
# SuperServer allocates 2048 pages for each database whilst Classic
# and SuperClassic allocate 75 pages per client connection per database.
#
# Type: integer
#
#DefaultDbCachePages = 2048

# ----------------------------
# Disk space preallocation
#
# Sets the amount of preallocated disk space in bytes. Disk space
# preallocation allows to reduce physical file fragmentation and to make 
# database work in out of disk space condition. With preallocation enabled,
# engine allocates 1/16nth of already allocated disk space at a time but 
# not less than 128KB and no more than DatabaseGrowthIncrement (128MB by 
# default). To disable preallocation set DatabaseGrowthIncrement to zero.
# Shadow database files are not preallocated.
#
# Type: integer
#
#DatabaseGrowthIncrement = 134217728

# ----------------------------
# File system cache threshold
#
# The threshold value that determines whether Firebird will use file system
# cache or not. File system caching is used if database cache size in pages 
# (configured explicitly in database header or via DefaultDbCachePages setting)
# is less than FileSystemCacheThreshold value.
#
# To use file system cache always set FileSystemCacheThreshold to a large value.
# To bypass file system cache for all databases set FileSystemCacheThreshold to 
# zero.
# 
# Type: integer, measured in database pages
#
#FileSystemCacheThreshold = 65536

# ----------------------------
# File system cache size
#
# This setting controls the maximum amount of RAM used by Windows file system
# cache on 64-bit Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 SP1 or later host. It has no
# effect for Unix hosts in this release yet.
#
# Note that the lowest number presently supported is 10%, and the highest number
# is 95%; numbers outside these limits will be set to the default of 30%.
#
# If the cache size has already been selected when the engine starts the host
# setting will not be changed. Thus you may need to reboot the host for the
# change of this setting to have effect.
#
# To leave host caching settings unchanged set this parameter to 0. This is
# the default parameter value.
#
# Security note
# To adjust the setting engine needs SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege right. Built-in
# service accounts and administrators have it by default. Installer grants this
# right to Firebird service account. If the engine fails to adjust the cache 
# size setting it will log warning message to the firebird.log and continue.
#
# Type: integer, measured in % of total physical RAM
#
#FileSystemCacheSize = 0

# ----------------------------
# Remove protection against opening databases on NFS mounted volumes on
# Linux/Unix and SMB/CIFS volumes on Windows.
#
# This also permits creating database shadows on mounted network volumes.
#
#     ***WARNING*** ***WARNING*** ***WARNING*** ***WARNING***
#
# This option removes an important safety feature of Firebird and can
# cause irrecoverable database corruption. Do not use this option unless
# you understand the risks and are prepared to accept the loss of the
# contents of your database.
# Unless this configuration option is changed from 0 to 1, Firebird can
# open a database only if the database is stored on a drive physically
# attached to the local computer - the computer running that copy of
# Firebird. Requests for connections to databases stored on NFS mounted
# drives are redirected to a Firebird server running on the computer that
# "owns" the disk.
# This restriction prevents two different copies of Firebird from opening
# the same database without coordinating their activities. Uncoordinated
# access by multiple copies of Firebird will corrupt a database. On a local
# system, the system-level file locking prevents uncoordinated access to
# the database file.
#
# NFS does not provide a reliable way to detect multiple users of a file on
# an NFS mounted disk. If a second copy of Firebird connects to a database on
# an NFS mounted disk, it will corrupt the database.
# Under some circumstances, running a Firebird server on the computer that
# owns NFS mounted volumes is inconvenient or impossible. Applications that
# use the "embedded" variant of Firebird and never share access to a database
# can use this option to permit direct access to databases on NFS mounted
# volumes.
#
# The situation for SMB/CIFS is quite similar to NFS with not all configurations
# providing file locking mechanisms needed for safe operation. Using SuperServer
# engine with the database on NT file server may be considered relatively safe 
# as file locking protects the database from being used by the several engines.
# Network stack can still change order of writes so you may get a corrupted
# database in case of network errors or power outage.
#
# The useful and safe case is working with a shared database marked read-only.
#
# DO NOT ENABLE THIS OPTION UNLESS YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#RemoteFileOpenAbility = 0

# ----------------------------
# Temporary space management
#
# Temporary storage is used by the sorting module, it's also
# intended to store temporary datasets etc.
#
# The parameters below handle the allocation and caching policy
# for the temporary space manager. In previous Firebird versions,
# they were prefixed with "SortMem" instead of current "Temp".
#
# The smallest block size being allocated in the temporary storage.
# This value reflects the allocation granularity.
#
# Type: integer
#
#TempBlockSize = 1048576

#
# The maximum amount of the temporary space that can be cached
# in memory.
#
# For Classic servers, this setting is defaulted to 8 MB.
# Although it can be increased, the value applies to each client
# connection/server instance and thus consumes a lot of memory.
#
# Type: integer
#
#TempCacheLimit = 67108864


# ----------------------------
# Boolean evaluation method (complete or shortcut)
#
# If your SQL code depends on side-effects of full evaluation of OR
# and AND statements (right-hand-side terms), even if the expressions
# final result could be determined by just examining the value of the
# first term, you might need to turn this on.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#CompleteBooleanEvaluation = 0


# ----------------------------
#
# Determines the number of seconds that the lock manager will wait after a
# conflict has been encountered before purging locks from dead processes
# and doing extra deadlock scan cycle. Engine detects deadlocks instantly
# in all normal cases, so this value affects things only if something goes
# wrong. Setting it too low may degrade system performance.
#
# Type: integer
#
#DeadlockTimeout = 10


# ----------------------------
#
# How often the pages are flushed on disk
# (for databases with ForcedWrites=Off only)
#
# Number of unflushed writes which will accumulate before they are
# flushed, at the next transaction commit.  For non-Win32 ports,
# the default value is -1 (Disabled)
#
# Type: integer
#
#MaxUnflushedWrites = 100

#
# Number of seconds during which unflushed writes will accumulate
# before they are flushed, at the next transaction commit. For non-Win32
# ports, the default value is -1 (Disabled)
#
# Type: integer
#
#MaxUnflushedWriteTime = 5


# ----------------------------
#
# This option controls whether to call abort() when internal error or BUGCHECK
# is encountered thus invoke post-mortem debugger which can dump core suitable
# for off-line analysis. When disabled engine tries to minimize damage and
# continue execution.
#
# Note that setting this option to 1 makes engine produce traceable coredumps
# when something nasty like SIGSEGV happens inside UDF. On Windows enabling
# this option makes engine invoke JIT debugger facilities when errors happen.
#
# For debugging builds (DEV_BUILD), default value is 1 (Enabled)
#
# Type: boolean
#
#BugcheckAbort = 0


# Prior to Firebird 1.5 various SELECT expressions generated unnamed
# columns. This did not conform to the SQL standard. Fb 1.5 saw the
# introduction of default aliases for these unnamed columns. In some
# cases, particularly if string concatenation is used (via the ||
# operator) this breaks existing scripts.
#
# This setting will affect aliases generated via CONCATENATION,
# CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and EXTRACT. Setting
# the value to true will disable the alias generation. It is only
# recommended to be used where legacy scripts need to be supported.
# It will be marked deprecated in Firebird 2.0 and removed in
# Firebird 3.0.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#OldColumnNaming = 0


# Prior to Firebird 2.5 the SET clause of the UPDATE statement assigned
# columns in the user-defined order with the NEW column values being
# immediately accessible to the subsequent assignments. This did not
# conform to the SQL standard. Starting with Firebird 2.5, only OLD column
# values are accessible to all the assignments of the SET clause.
#
# Example of the old vs new behaviour:
#
# UPDATE T SET A = B, B = A
# old result: A gets equal to B, B doesn't change
# new result: A and B get their values exchanged
#
# Change this configuration option to 1 (true) only if your SQL code relies
# on the legacy semantics of the SET clause. It's provided as a temporary
# solution for backward compatibility issues and will be deprecated in
# future Firebird versions.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#OldSetClauseSemantics = 0


# ----------------------------
# Relaxing relation alias checking rules in SQL
#
# Since Firebird 2.0, strict alias checking rules were implemented in the SQL
# parser to accord with the SQL standard requirements. This setting allows
# these rules to be relaxed in order to allow legacy applications to run on 
# Firebird 2.0.
# A setting of 1 (true) allows the parser to resolve a qualified column reference 
# using the relation name, where an alias has been specified for that relation.
#
# For example, it allows a query such as:
#       SELECT TABLE.X FROM TABLE A
#
# It is not recommended to enable this setting. It should be regarded as an 
# interim workaround for porting untidy legacy code, until it is practicable to 
# revise such code. 
# 
# CAUTION!
# There is no guarantee that this setting will be available in future Firebird 
# versions.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#RelaxedAliasChecking = 0


# ----------------------------
# Client Connection Settings (Basic)
#
# Seconds to wait before concluding an attempt to connect has failed.
#
# Type: integer
#
#ConnectionTimeout = 180

#
# Seconds to wait on a silent client connection before the server sends
# dummy packets to request acknowledgment.
#
# NOTE. This option may hang or crash Windows NT4 or Windows 2000 pre SP3 
# on the client side as explained here: 
# http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=296265.
# or may not prevent eventual inactive client disconnection for other OS.
#
# Normally, Firebird uses SO_KEEPALIVE socket option to keep track of
# active connections. If you do not like default 2-hour keepalive timeout
# then adjust your server OS settings appropriately. On UNIX-like OS's,
# modify contents of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_*. On Windows,
# follow instrutions of this article:
# http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=140325
#
# Type: integer
#
#DummyPacketInterval = 0


# ----------------------------
# TCP Protocol Settings
#
# The TCP Service name/Port number to be used for client database
# connections.
#
# It is only necessary to change one of the entries, not both.  The
# order of precendence is the 'RemoteServiceName' (if an entry is
# found in the 'services.' file) then the 'RemoteServicePort'.
#
# Type: string, integer
#
#RemoteServiceName = gds_db
#RemoteServicePort = 3050

#
# The TCP Port Number to be used for server Event Notification
# messages.  The value of 0 (Zero) means that the server will choose
# a port number randomly.
#
# Type: integer
#
#RemoteAuxPort = 0

#
# TCP/IP buffer size for send and receive buffers of both the client
# and server. The engine reads ahead of the client and can send
# several rows of data in a single packet. The larger the packet size,
# the more data is sent per transfer. Range is 1448 to 32767 (MAX_SSHORT).
#
# Type: integer
#
#TcpRemoteBufferSize = 8192

#
# Either enables or disables Nagle algorithm (TCP_NODELAY option of
# socket) of the socket connection.
#
# Note: Currently is a default for classic and super servers.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#TcpNoNagle = 1

#
# Allows incoming connections to be bound to the IP address of a
# specific network card. It enables rejection of incoming connections
# through any other network interface except this one. By default,
# connections from any available network interface are allowed.
# If you are using Classic Server, this setting is for Windows only.
# Under Linux, BSD or Mac OS X, with Classic server use xinetd or launchd
# configuration file (bind parameter).
#
# Type: string
#
#RemoteBindAddress =


# ----------------------------
# Locking and shared memory parameters
#
# Bytes of shared memory allocated for lock manager.
# In Classic mode, the size given is used for the initial allocation. The
# table expands dynamically up to the limit of memory. In SuperServer, the
# initial size is also the final size.
#
# Type: integer
#
#LockMemSize = 1048576

#
# When a connection wants to lock an object, it gets a lock request
# block which specifies the object and the lock level requested. Each
# locked object has a lock block. Request blocks are connected to those
# lock blocks either as requests that have been granted, or as pending
# requests.
#
# The settings:
#   1 means locks are granted first come, first served.
#   0 means emulate InterBase v3.3 behavior, where locks are granted
#     as soon as they are available; can result in lock request
#       starvation.
#
# Type: integer/boolean
#
#LockGrantOrder = 1

#
# In Classic, only one client process may access the lock table at any
# time. Access to the lock table is governed by a mutex. The mutex can
# be requested conditionally - a wait is a failure and the request must
# be retried - or unconditionally - the request will wait until it is
# satisfied. This parameter establishes the number of attempts that
# will be made conditionally. Zero value means unconditional mode.
# Relevant only on SMP machines.
#
# Type: integer
#
#LockAcquireSpins = 0

#
# Tune lock hash list; more hash slots mean shorter hash chains. Only
# necessary under very high load. Prime number values are recommended.
#
# Type: integer
#
#LockHashSlots = 1009

# ----------------------------
#
# Bytes of shared memory allocated for event manager.
#
# Type: integer
#
#EventMemSize = 65536


# ===========================
# SuperServer Engine Settings
# ===========================
#
# ----------------------------
# Which CPUs should be used (Windows Only)
#
# In an SMP system, sets which processors can be used by the server.
# The value is taken from a bit map in which each bit represents a CPU.
# Thus, to use only the first processor, the value is 1. To use both
# CPU 1 and CPU 2, the value is 3. To use CPU 2 and CPU 3, the value
# is 6. The default value is 1.
#
# Type: integer
#
#CpuAffinityMask = 1


# ----------------------------
# Settings for the thread scheduler  (Windows Only)
#
# If you have problems with computer response time, running firebird
# on workstation, turn off thread scheduler.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#UsePriorityScheduler = 1

#
# The wait time, in milli-seconds (ms), before the priority of:
#   - an active thread is reduced to 'Low', or
#   - an inactive thread is increased to 'High'
#
# Note: The default value was chosen based on experiments on Intel
# PIII/P4 processors.  It should be increased for using in the computer
# with lower speed processors.
#
# Type: integer
#
#PrioritySwitchDelay = 100

#
# Number of additional 'intervals' given to a 'High' priority thread.
#
# Type: integer
#
#PriorityBoost = 5

# ----------------------------
# Garbage collection policy
#
# Defines how engine does garbage collection. Valid values are :
#   cooperative
#   background
#   combined
#
# Note: this setting affects SuperServer only.
#
# ClassicServer (and SuperClassic) implements "cooperative" only, therefore it 
# uses "cooperative" policy regardless of the value.
#
# SuperServer implements all three policies and uses "combined" by default.
#
# Type: string (special format)
#
#GCPolicy = combined


# ==============================
# Classic Server Engine Settings
# ==============================
#


# ==============================
# Settings for Windows platforms
# ==============================
#
# ----------------------------
# Does the guardian restart the server every time it crashes?
#    0 - only start the engine/service once
#    1 - always restart the engine/service if it terminates
#
# Type: integer/boolean
#
#GuardianOption = 1


#
# ----------------------------
# Priority level/class for the server process.
#
# The values are:
#     0 (Zero) - normal priority,
#     positive value - high priority (same as -B command line option)
#     negative value - low priority.
#
# Note: All changes to this value should be carefully tested to ensure
# that engine is more responsive to requests.
#
# Type: integer
#
#ProcessPriorityLevel = 0


# ----------------------------
# Local Connection Settings
#
# The name of the shared memory area used as a transport channel in local protocol.
# Note that the local protocol in v2.0 is not compatible with any previous version
# if Firebird or InterBase.
#
# Please note that the server can register objects in Global\ kernel namespace
# only if it runs under the account with SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_NAME privilege.
# This means that if you run the server under a restricted account under
# Windows Vista/XP SP2/2000 SP4 it will not be accessible using the
# local protocol from other sessions.
#
# Type: string
#
#IpcName = FIREBIRD

#
# The name of the pipe used as a transport channel in NetBEUI protocol.
# Has the same meaning as a port number for TCP/IP. The default value is
# compatible with IB/FB1.
#
# Type: string
#
#RemotePipeName = interbas


# ============================
# Settings for Unix/Linux platforms
# ============================

# ----------------------------
# Remove protection against redirecting requests to other servers
#
#     ***WARNING*** ***WARNING*** ***WARNING*** ***WARNING***
#
# Ability to redirect requests to other servers was initially present
# in Interbase, but was broken by Borland in Interbase 6.0, when
# they added SQL dialects. Request redirection was fixed in firebird 2.0,
# but today such behaviour (proxy) seems to be dangerous from security
# point of view. Imagine, you have one carefully protected firebird server,
# access to which is possible from global net. But in case when this server
# has access to your internal LAN (may and should be restricted,
# but often possible), it will work as a gateway for incoming requests like:
# firebird.your.domain.com:internal_server:/private/database.fdb
# It's enough to know name/IP of some internal server on your LAN, and for
# this connection one even need not know login/password on external server.
# Such gateway easily overrides firewall, installed to protect your LAN
# from outside attack.
#
# DO NOT ENABLE THIS OPTION UNLESS YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.
#
# Type: boolean
#
#Redirection = 0

#######################################
#
# KB to Bytes Conversion table
#
#######################################
#
#    KB     Bytes         KB     Bytes
#   ----    ---------    ----    ---------
#      1    1024           32    32768
#      2    2048           64    65536
#      4    4096          128    131072
#      8    8192          256    262144
#     16    16384         512    524288
#
#######################################
#
# MB to Bytes Conversion table
#
#######################################
#
#    MB    Bytes           MB    Bytes            MB    Bytes
#   ---    ---------      ---    -----------     ---    -----------
#     1    1048576         64    67108864        448    469762048
#     2    2097152        128    134217728       512    536870912
#     4    4194304        192    201326592       640    671088640
#     8    8388608        256    268435456       768    805306368
#    16    16777216       320    335544320       896    939524096
#    32    33554432       384    402653184      1024    1073741824
#
```

- I have tried `DatabaseAccess = None`, `DatabaseAccess = Full`, `DatabaseAccess = Restrict /home/tomay/Firebird/GEA.fdb` and `DatabaseAccess = Restrict /home/tomay/Firebird`.
- I have edited '**/etc/firebird/aliases.conf**' as follows:

```
# ------------------------------
# List of known database aliases
# ------------------------------

#
# Example Database:
#
employee.fdb = no/employee.fdb
employee = no/employee.fdb

#
# Live Databases:
#
GEA = /home/tomay/Firebird/GEA.fdb
```

Here are some screenshots of my connection tries:
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I am missing here?

I just want to see it connect.

Comment: Could you please specify **how** you connect, including the connection string or connection properties/configuration?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have updated my question to add some connection tries screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to create a new folder `/databases/` in root directory, gave it `firebird` **user** and **group** permissions and put the database in there.

I have tried this time, and voila! the connection established and the database is opened.

- It turns out that the default Firebird location for databases in arch linux is: `/var/lib/firebird/` which have the `firebird` **user** and **group** permissions by default. So after copying my .fdb database to this location I had to `chown` it too:
  `sudo chown firebird.firebird /var/lib/firebird/*.fdb`.
- **Conclusion**: never put the database somewhere in the user directory.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems

1. When you use `DatabaseAccess = None` you can only connect using the alias defined in `aliases.conf` (or `databases.conf` in Firebird 3 and higher), not by specifying the database path.

   So, for example in FlameRobin in the field 'Database path' you should use `GEA` instead of the path `/home/tomay/Firebird/GEA.fdb`.
2. Firebird is - normally - a server process, and the user for a server process does not normally have access to a normal users home directory.

   You need to put the database outside of your home directory, and make sure both the folder and the file itself have sufficient access rights for the user running the firebird process (usually the user firebird), or to the group containing that user (usually the group firebird).

   Specifically, the directory should be `drwxrwx---` (or chmod 770) to the firebird group and user), and the file should be `-rw-rw----` (or chmod 660) to the firebird group and user. See also [What file and directory permissions to set for database files on Linux?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq40/)

Also, if you use `isql-fb GEA` instead of `isql-fb localhost:GEA`, the database will be accessed using Firebird Embedded and not through the server process, and in that case your own user will need sufficient access to the database file and certain shared lock files as well. You can achieve this by adding yourself to the firebird group and logging out and back in.